# Regex number format no consercutive - - in between number

Tags: regex

I current have this regex:

```
/^\+?\d+(\d|\-)+\d+$/
```

this accepts

```
12345
123-456
+12345
+12345-12345
```

my problem that this also accepts

```
123--123
123-------3242-324324
```

How can I fix the regex to not accept consecutive dash in between numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be correct one

```
^\+?\d+(-\d+)*$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cC4sL5/1)**

or modifying a bit of your regex with negative lookahead will also work

```
^(?!.*--)\+?\d+(\d|\-)+\d+$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cC4sL5/2)**